# TypeScript: assign implemented class to variable typed as base class

Tags: inheritance, typescript

I want to create a base class which other classes will implement and/or extend.  The derived classes are doing this because they share much identical functionality, but sometimes have their own spin on a piece of it.

```
abstract class Human {
    constructor(protected _name:string) {
    }

    protected identify():string {
        return this._name;
    }

    abstract doTrick():void;
}

class Boy extends Human {
    private jump():void {
        console.log("jumping");
    }

    private doTrick():void {
        this.jump();
    }
}
```

This works fine.  A `Boy` can be created and he'll say his name based on what `Human` says to do when `identify()` happens.  The problem hits here:

```
var person:Human = new Boy("Bob");
```

I want to do this because I have a variety of `Human` derived classes and I don't want to do have to do `var person:Boy|Girl|Man|Child|Dinosaur|Whatever`.  Problem is that doing so causes `error TS2322: Type 'Boy' is not assignable to type 'Human'`.

I feel like I should be able to type `person` as `Human` even though I'm assigning the derived `Boy` class to it, since the `Boy` class is just an implementation of the `Human` class.

What am I missing?

Comment: You said *where* the problem is, but not *what* the problem is.  Is it not allowing the assignment?  What error does it give you?

Comment: The only problem I get with your code is that the compiler complains that `Human.doTrick` is public but it's private in `Boy.doTrick`.  If you change them both to protected then it's all good.  As @Amy said, what exactly is the problem/error?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the error:   error TS2322: Type 'Boy' is not assignable to type 'Human'.

Comment: Huh.  Strange.  Fixing the public vs protected problem actually fixed it.  I guess the mismatch caused the implementation contract to not be recognized.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just to be clear, the problem was not that the contract was not recognized, the problem was that the contract of `Boy` wasn't compatible with `Human`. Since `Human` requires a publicly available `doTrick`-method, an object with a private `doTrick` does not fulfill `Human`.